# Mongoose updateMany using field from each document (this?)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to run an updateMany to populate a new field with an existing field's content.

My idea of the code would be:

```
const filter = { 'somefield': 'somevalue' }
const update = { 'newfield': this.somefield }
await Model.updateMany(filter, update)
```

But that is not valid. Any advice appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to put `$set` in updated clause.

```
const filter = { 'somefield': 'somevalue' }
const updateDoc = { $set: { 'newfield': this.somefield } }
const result = await Model.updateMany(filter, updateDoc);
console.log(`Updated ${result.modifiedCount} documents`);
```

Comment: This didn't work I'm afraid

Comment: This is what written in Mongodb documentation, I doubt why its not working? Can you please log the error and share your logs.